# R deSolve with DLL does not handle the ip parameter

Tags: r, desolve

In the *R Package deSolve, Writing Code in Compiled Languages* there is a prototype and example

`void derivs (int *neq, double *t, double *y, double *ydot,double *yout, int *ip)`

The documentation says:

> *ip points to an integer vector whose length is at least 3; the first element (ip[0]) contains the number of output values (which should be equal or larger than nout), its second element contains the length of *yout, and the third element contains the length of *ip; next are integer values, as passed by parameter ipar when calling the integrator.

But in fact there is no way to pass *ip to your C or Fortran derivs subroutine. To get code to run you have to call ode() with a named parameter nout because the routine that checks and loads the DLL requires it. However, the value passed for nout becomes ip(1) in the Fortran derivs subroutine.

It is not clear to me what is going on.  The output from the example in the vignette is a matrix dim(13,7) while the values in ip() in the derivs() subroutine is always ip(1) = nout, ip(2) = nout+2, ip(3) = 4.  The output is exactly the same independent of the value of nout.

If have the deSolve source code and grep searches for ip being declared or set yield NULL.

Does ip have any role in the actual calculation?

Answer (score 0):

The `*ip` argument is passed to the `derivs` function by the solver. The solver is initialized by the initializer, e.g. `N` in the `odec` function below that calls `odeparms` with the number of parameters.

The number of external outputs `*ip` is initialized from R by the `nout` argument:

```r
lsoda(y, times, func, parms, rtol = 1e-6, atol = 1e-6,
  jacfunc = NULL, jactype = "fullint", rootfunc = NULL,
  verbose = FALSE, nroot = 0, tcrit = NULL,
  hmin = 0, hmax = NULL, hini = 0, ynames = TRUE,
  maxordn = 12, maxords = 5, bandup = NULL, banddown = NULL,
  maxsteps = 5000, dllname = NULL, initfunc = dllname,
  initpar = parms, rpar = NULL, ipar = NULL, nout = 0,
  outnames = NULL, forcings = NULL, initforc = NULL,
  fcontrol = NULL, events = NULL, lags = NULL,...)
```

Here a C example using `yout`. The full source code of the example can be found in files `odec.c` and `odedll.R` on [R-Forge](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/deSolve/inst/doc/dynload/?root=desolve).

```c
#include <R.h> /* gives F77_CALL through R_ext/RS.h */

static double parms[3];

#define k1 parms[0]
#define k2 parms[1]
#define k3 parms[2]

/* initializer: same name as the dll (without extension) */
void odec(void (* odeparms)(int *, double *)) {
    int N=3;
    odeparms(&N, parms);
}

/* Derivatives */
void derivsc(int *neq, double *t, double *y, double *ydot, double *yout, int*ip) {
    if (ip[0] <3) error("nout should be at least 3");
    ydot[0] = -k1*y[0] + k2*y[1]*y[2];
    ydot[2] = k3 * y[1]*y[1];
    ydot[1] = -ydot[0]-ydot[2];
    
    yout[0] = y[0]+y[1]+y[2];
    yout[1] = y[0]*2;
    yout[2] = k3;
}
```

Comment: I can run the example and I have the deSolve source code.  However I am still confused by the odeparms() call.  In the source code for deSolve there are 9 'odeparms' references.        All are either C function declarations (either at the top level or as the declaration of the function in the call).  The src code calls 'odeparms()' which is declared but never defined.  Where is the code for 'odeparms()'?

Comment: This is a rather special C construct. The function is defined inline as a hook to set global variables. It is referenced by its pointer via `initfunc` in the caller of the solver, e.g. in `call_lsoda` or (somewhat simpler) in `call_rk4`. Similar, but less tricky with `nout` that is used to allocate memory for the auxiliary outputs. 

To see when it is called, add a line `Rprintf("odec called\n");` to the function, and to see that its name does not matter outside its defining function, just replace the two occurrences of `odecall` with something else, e.g. `foo` and it will work too.

Comment: I'm doing my coding in Fortran.  The example Fortran `initmod()` which I follow is simply `subroutine initmod4(odeparms)
  external odeparms
  double precision parms(16)
  common /myparms/parms
  call odeparms(16, parms)
  return
end subroutine initmod4`   There is no Fortran subroutine `odeparms()` and I have no idea how in the scope of the Fortran subroutine `parms` is defined.  It's a dynamically loaded subroutine, there is no Fortran main program to define a global `parms`.  All very difficult for a retired Fortran using PhD scientist.

Comment: Yes, this sort of back-calls in deSolve is internally tricky. The good news is, that  you don't need to take care much about this. Just follow the code examples, e.g. the one in `odefor.f`. In the Fortran version it is even more clear, that `odeparms` is a parameter of a function pointing itself to a function. It gets its value (i.e. the particular function) from the caller, `e.g. call_rk4`. BTW, things like this are possibly better discussed in a mailing list or directly.

Comment: I have it working but it appears in the example code and the, to me, hidden `odeparms` that there is no way to have a dynamic number of equations.  That is the number of `parms` is fixed at compile time because the `parms` common block takes a constant or parameter known at compile time.   The R `parms` has to match in length.  The number of coupled equations is a primary independent variable in my work.  This design of deSolve then requires a separate DLL for every choice of `neq`, which for me will be on the order of 10,000.  To an old Fortran user this appears bad design.

Comment: The design decisions of deSolve have good reasons, and it is free software used by thousands of people. You are free to use any other software that solves your problems better, or to implement the models in pure R. Then, memory allocation is completely dynamic and it is still fast, If the systems can be described in form of matrices. And, it is also possible to use a code generator like [odin](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=odin). Finally, it is also possible to use the original [ODEPACK](https://computing.llnl.gov/projects/odepack/software) Fortran integrators directly.